# Сортировка пользователей по активности

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Пытаюсь отсортировать пользователей по колонке last_active, при этом важно отображать онлайн пользователей (`last_active >= datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=5)`) сверху списка отсортированные по ID.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(16), index=True, nullable=False)
    last_active = db.Column(db.DateTime)


def get_result():
    online_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=5)
    users= User.query.order_by(case(
            (User.last_active >= online_time, online_time),
            else_=User.last_active).desc())

    return users.limit(10).all()
```

Ловлю следующую ошибку:

```
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 2431, in __init__
    whenlist = [
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 2433, in <listcomp>
    for (c, r) in whens
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 432, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 759, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 432, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
    
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 67, in operate
    return o[0](self.expr, op, *(other + o[1:]), **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py", line 237, in _getitem_impl
    _unsupported_impl(expr, op, other, **kw)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py", line 241, in _unsupported_impl
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
```

Вариант сначала получить список, а потом отсортировать не особо интересен. Пытаюсь реализовывать верный запрос с использованием SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(16), index=True, nullable=False)
    last_active = db.Column(db.DateTime)


def get_result():
    online_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=5)
    users= User.query.order_by(case(
            [(User.last_active >= online_time, online_time)],
            else_=User.last_active).desc())

    return users.limit(10).all()
```

`case` принимает список объектов tuple, а не сам tuple.